# Switch statement with do while loop

Tags: loops, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a code that will ask a user to input a number and every number have a message, for example:

```
1-2 Buckle your shoes
3-4 Shut the door
5-6 Pick up sticks
7-8 Lay them straight
9-10 Begin again
```

But if the user input 9 or 10 it will ask a number again to repeat it.

When I'm trying to enter 9 or 10 it wont repeat. Can anyone help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class javaQuiz4try2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;

    boolean x = false;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a number(1-10)");
    number=sc.nextInt();
    
    switch(number){
    case 1: 
        case 2:
        System.out.println("Buckle my shoe");
        x=true;
        break;
    case 3:
        case 4:
        System.out.println("Shut the door");
        x=true;
        break;
    
    case 5:
        case 6:
        System.out.println("Pick up sticks");
        x=true;
        break;
    case 7:
        case 8:
        System.out.println("Lay them straight");
        x=true;
        break;  
    case 9:
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Begin again");
        x=false;
        break;
        }
            }while(number<=9);
        
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to include relevant code and your attempt at solving this issue. If you don't know how to write loops, Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code:

Loop forever:

- ask for input from user
- capture input
- if input is between 1 and 8 inclusive exit loop
- display “invalid input”